# SensorEventListener not unregistering itself

Tags: android, listener, sensors, sensormanager

I have been developing an application which needs to perform accelerometer calibration in several steps.

What I have done, is create a SensorEventListener that gets a certain amount of readings, and after that amount is reached, I call 'sensorManager().unregisterListener(eventListener)'.

However, I think this line is not unregistering the listener, since immediately afterwards, the same line is called, as a result of continuing to run.

Question: am I doing things properly this way, or should condition my handler so that after reaching this condition it doesn't allow itself to run (using if's)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SensorEventListener only gets called once after you've unregistered it then this behaviour is probably due to a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software), due to the multi-threaded nature of Android.  So if you want to shut off processing the readings, then (as you suggest) you should set a boolean variable and test it with if statements to ensure no further processing once you've reached your limit.

Comment: I thought there was a single thread for each listener, but that was a bit naive, I guess. Should the boolean be synchronized? Or was that only necessary if the state changed back and forth?

Comment: On most operating systems, a setting or testing Boolean should be an atomic operation, so synchronizing just to test or check a boolean shouldn't be necessary. However, synchronization may be necessary to to get the behavior that you're looking for.